# Javascript:: Is it possible to create an array of new audio objects?

Tags: javascript, audio, asynchronous, mp3, synchronization

This example work perfectly :

```
var audio=new Audio();
audio.src="Hezi.mp3";
audio.play();
```

But I was wondering if there is a possibility to create an array of new audio objects like such:

```
var audio[0]=new Audio();
audio[0].src="Hezi.mp3";
audio[0].play();

var audio[1]=new Audio();
audio[1].src="Gangina.mp3";
audio[1].play();
```

Off-course the second example is not the current syntax but just so you can get the idea...

Comment: @Pointy Off-course :) It's not working otherwise I wouldn't post it :)

Comment: first declare audio as a empty array and then add Audio() objects, like this var audio= new Array();
audio[0]=new Audio();
audio[0].src="Hezi.mp3";
audio[0].play();

Comment: @vasilenicusor Thank you sooooooooooooooooooooo much ! I love you! :*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to adjust it somewhat... plus you probably don't want to attempt to play them all at once - and actually adding them to the DOM will allow you to give controls to the user.

```
var audio = [];

audio[0]=new Audio();
audio[0].src="Hezi.mp3";
audio[0].play();

audio[1]=new Audio();
audio[1].src="Gangina.mp3";
audio[1].play();
```

Comment: Actually I do want to play them all at once :) Thank you @Steve Fenton and vasilenicusor !!!